# ConEmu: how to open a standard windows cmd.exe window from conemu (and execute a command - e.g. start a batch file)

Tags: conemu

I need to open a legacy app which requires a standard cmd.exe
I would like to be able to spawn it from a batch file (.bat) and run it from command line in ConEmu
Don't see a way to do that.
*start* and *cmd* open a new tab in ConEmu at best - while I need the legacy cmd.exe window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like I found a way - rather non-obvious but it seems to work:

```
[start] conhost cmd /c <your command>
```

or (if you want cmd window to continue beyond the execution of your command):

```
[start] conhost cmd /k <your command>
```

start in front is optional (useful if you don't want to block the original conemu terminal until completion of your command).